# Why does clearing cache fix Snapdragon 820 overheating issues?

Tags: cache, overheating

I was researching whether Snapdragon 820 has overheating issues like 810, and found numerous advice on both LG G5 and Samsung Galaxy S7 that says "yes, overheating can happen, and **to fix it, clear the cache**, possibly followed by factory reset".

<sub>[Example](http://recomhub.com/blog/how-to-fix-lg-g5-overheating-problem/), [example](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/galaxy-s7-edge-problems/3/)</sub>.

However, none of the articles had any explanation on how clearing the cache would help.

## Is there a reason it would help fix overheating? How?

Comment: Before wiping cache (if you did), did you make a copy of it for forensics? It would possibly be having something that could lead to understanding of solution.

Comment: @Firelord - I don't own the phone. I want to understand why this proposed solution would work, before deciding to get 820 based device.

Comment: I see no reason to believe this would work, but it's certainly *possible* if some poor coding within Android does intensive operations on old cache files for strange reasons.